# My subview is not responding click event

Tags: iphone, ios, gridview, touch

I am creating a app that display subview like ActionSheetView and in that i have added UIGridView and UIPageControll thru outlet , but now when i click the cell it does not respond ,my subview is a ViewController with the nib file.

and if i create a button and add in my popupview programmatically then  it wil displaying, and also get the click event, but anything in outlet does not respond.

i have tried to set userinteraction enable in my subview but it does not done any good.

here is my code for first view that display subview by clicking barbutton:

```
- (void)popUpView:(id)sender {
    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

   bGView = [[UIView alloc] init];   /this is the background view and all view is added in it
    bGView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,490);
    bGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    bGView.alpha = 0.8 ;

    CGRect  viewFrame = CGRectMake(10, 90, 300, 300);
    aPopUpViewController = [[PopUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil];        //this is my view controller and when this shows on screen it display my greed view

    aPopUpViewController.view.frame = viewFrame; 
    aPopUpViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [bGView addSubview:aPopUpViewController.view];

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(-1, 80, 30, 30);
    [bGView addSubview:button];

    //for view animation

    /*
    // from bottom to center animation

    [bGView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is OFF screen!
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [bGView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is ON screen!
    [UIView commitAnimations];*/

    //for page like effect

    /*[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp //change to whatever animation you like
                    animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:bGView]; }
                    completion:nil];*/

    /*CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
     transition.duration = 1.0;
     transition.type = kCATransitionReveal; //choose your animation
     [bGView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
     [self.view addSubview:bGView];*/

    aPopUpViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    bGView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    bGView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        bGView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // do something once the animation finishes, put it here
    }];

     [self.view addSubview:bGView];


    addLabel.enabled = NO;
    clipArt.enabled = NO;
    emailItem.enabled = NO;
    closeButton.enabled = NO;
    self.navigationController.topViewController.title = @"Choose ClipArt";

    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];

   theDataObject.navBarHide = @"no";

}

- (void)aMethod:(id)sender
{
    //[aPopUpViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    //[button removeFromSuperview];

    /*[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve//change to whatever animation you like
                    animations:^ { [bGView removeFromSuperview]; }
                    completion:nil];*/

    [bGView removeFromSuperview];

    addLabel.enabled = YES;
    clipArt.enabled = YES;
    emailItem.enabled = YES;
    closeButton.enabled = YES;

    self.navigationController.topViewController.title = @"Greeting's";

    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];

    theDataObject.navBarHide = @"yes";
}
```

and this is how my screen look like
[image]

**UPDATE**

now i figured out my problem,problem is that i have given my whole view a tap listner,now i am adding grid view as subview so when ever i tap on cell rather then do select cell it will generate view tap gesture and thats why cell never selected,that's what i think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line after you add every subviews in your main view..

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourGridView];
```

Comment: but my gridview is not subview it is added in my second view controller, like MMGridView.still this work?

Comment: any where you add the gridview just write this code dude.. like [yourView bringSubviewToFront:yourGridView];

Comment: it have make my grideview in front but still touche does not display.

Comment: you give the delegate it from outlets??

Comment: problem is not with delegate, if i put button in outlet than it will also does not reply to touch , i have tried it.

Comment: i am sure dude you put some overlay or some view as a superview of your mainview so just check the flow and at last or end of whole method just set the gridview as a superview dude.....

Comment: if any view is on gridview than its also does not scroll,but it scrolling perfectly.

Comment: then its point of gridview and 3 possiblity here for this problem is 1.Check its User Interaction Enabled = yes 2. something override on this gridview and 3. if you set the gridview as a parent then give the delegate propely in your main class ...

Comment: now i figured out my problem,problem is that i have given my whole view a tap listner,now i am adding grid view as subview so when ever i tap on cell rather then do select cell it will generate view tap gesture and thats why cell never selected,that's what i think..

Comment: now working fine ?? and just i say that its not a front of the view something cover the gridview only..

Comment: still stuck at touch event .

Comment: can you remove the geasture and then try it??